# Linux hang on transfer of big files with rsync

Tags: kernel, rsync, slackware

I had a big trouble.

My os is Slackware,14.2,I  have to backup a lot of data

2,5TB.

I have tried many methods: usb3,firewire,e-sata

with different control.

After some hours,sometimes minutes the system totally hang

no way to recover: power button,sysrq,the only way is to

cut-off the AC power.On console I cannot see any error message

because the keyboard is hanged.

I have tried different kernels,compiled by myself or precompiled slackware.

But no way

I have also change all dimms,and try memtest,no errors

but still hang

My hw is ASUS M5A97 R2.0 with 16GB of ram

I have to change my mobo?Or whatelse?

I forget the most important thing: the backup is on disk encrypted with luks.

Can be related to [this](http://billauer.co.il/blog/2010/10/disk-io-scheduler-load-dd-freeze-stall-hang/)?

Comment: Your system hangs when you are running a back up?

Comment: So it's capable of running memtest, but doesn't boot from the disk? Then the disk or disk controller can be the culprit...

Comment: The disk boot,but every time I will try to backup with rsync.,.hang totally

Comment: You need to monitor your system resource as you are performing the rsync.

Comment: System resource seems ok,free -m report 10G ram free,iotop 99% ,top 10%

Comment: Check the external disk for errors.
consider a remote ssh session(s) where you have a tail on /var/log/{syslog|messages|daemon.log} as well as frequent dmesg outputs, and another with vmstat and another with iostat running

Comment: I believe either your system io chips, say, usb/firewire, etc, or the external device chips, are overheating and failing due to the large data volume. I've seen this happen. The fact that slack itself is crashing to my mind suggests the issue is on your main board, or cards directly attached to it via the pci or pcie bus, ie, usb, esata card, etc. Usually when external device chips overheat and fail, the thing just slows down, and maybe stops, but the system itself is still running fine. Failing hardware is something that can certainly crash the kernel, which is what is happening to you.

Comment: Sadly, of all the things that one can test, like ram, hard disks, etc, motherboard tests aren't nearly as consistent or reliable, and if the issue only happens during large file transfer/writes, then you might not be able to duplicate it in a test anyway. I'd strip off everything extra re system hardware, and test the most direct mobo to backup device connection, using rsync, just because rsync works better. 10 to 1 it's mainboard related. Also try simple cp as well just to make sure you aren't tripping some obscure rsync bug, though I doubt that's the case.

Comment: What version of `rsync`? What command line are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found.

I had a custom kernel,probably some strange settings make rsync hang

with the Slackware current kernel 4.4+ works fine,even with the 4.4.88

Slackware-14.2 kernel

With those kernels no problems,no hang.